# how to read power labels on home appliances?

Tags: power-consumption, tag

I want to know how to read the power label of a home appliance in order to estimate energy cost.

I have provided a picture of an example power label

[image: power label]

What i understand from the provided label is I use the rated power as its the power that an appliances will ever reach on high power?

the t1 and t3 energy are based on the T climates?

Comment: Your use case is also important in determining how much power your appliances will consume.  A refrigerator in a hot place that has the door opened frequently will have much higher energy use than one in a cold basement that has the door opened once a month.

Comment: @JohnD can you interpret the label in layman terms in relation to kwh consumption? thanks

Comment: Well, the label gives 2 conditions, T1 and T3, whatever they are.  During those conditions, if the label is to be believed, the unit will draw 1430 W and 1680 W respectively.  You would not expect it to draw more than the rated power input of 2200 W under any conditions, but that's about all you can get from the label.  As @Andyaka said, the label may not be reliable so a wattmeter would be the best way to figure out what the thing draws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T1: ambient temperature range of -7° to +35°
T3: ambient temperature range of -7° to +52°

Energy usage is power * time, usually in kilowatt-hours. But, that's only part of the story.

The cost is dependent on ambient temperature, duty cycle of the device, and many other factors that affect the duty cycle like thermal insulation quality, thermal leaks, other appliances adding heat to the environment, people adding heat to the environment, ...

If your device plugs in to a wall outlet, there are meters to record power usage of devices over time such as the [Kill-A-Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/p4400.html) line of meters. Recording power usage over 1 week will give you a good idea of cost of running such an appliance.

Comment: sure i get all the other stuff that might affect the power consumption. but based on the label it will not exceed 2.2 kwh even under the most unfavorable conditions and similarly it will not go under 1.4kwh (the t1 condition) even under the most favorable conditions. am i correct? thanks.

Comment: @user117582 You are correct. However, all this label tells you is how the circuit supplying power should be sized. The compressor is switched on and off to maintain temperature set level. Figuring out cost to operate needs a meter to tally up usage over time for your particular installation.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the current rating of 11.2 A is used with all other appliances to not exceed the breaker rating. Actual steady state power depends on the ambient and supply tolerance on 240V & fan speed.